# Assign a domain when deploying a .Net API with NGINX on Ubuntu

Tags: .net, asp.net-core, ubuntu, nginx

I deployed a .Net Core API to my Ubuntu machine using nginx. I can access it with my IP, but I'll soon need to deploy it to an Ubuntu VPS, and I have bought a `.com` domain, how do I assign that domain so when I enter it on the browser I can use the API endpoints? I'm quite newbie on those kind of things.

Comment: We would need the NGINX configuration. Without it it is all guessing. In the NGINX configuration, the `server_name` can be used to bind the HTTP Server Configuration to your VHost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1)First you have to configure your ip address to the domain name with an A record when you purchase it. the ip address will be the public IP address of your Ubuntu VPS where your .NET Core API is deployed.

2)Create a new Nginx configuration file in `/etc/nginx/sites-available/`:

```
sudo nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/yourdomain.com
```

Insert the following configuration, adjusted for your domain and application paths:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;

        location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000; # Replace with the port your app is running on
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection keep-alive;
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
            proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
        }
    }
```

3)Link the configuration file from `sites-available` to `sites-enabled`:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/yourdomain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
```

4)Reload Nginx to apply changes:

```
sudo systemctl reload nginx
```